# How to add data in to particular row by searching a Id in excel vb

Tags: excel, vba

I am not familiar with Excel VB. I have a search bar and I want to get the details by entering the style No(column C) from  column `A:H`. I have the data entry in excel sheet. `I:J` columns need to be added.
When i enter the style No in search bar, all the details are displaying 
for the column I & J i have two textbox named `txtIssueDate` & `txtActualIssued`.

I want to add the details for the empty fields for a particular row the which style no that i have searched in search bar.

I need to code for update button for those two textboxes when i search in search bar the details will display, i need to update the details for those textboxes [My Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVpzE.png)

I have attached dashboard [Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSiT1.png).

Search Button Code:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox7_DropButtonClick()
    TextBox7_DropButtonClick.Caption = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")
End Sub
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim iSearch     As Long, i As Long
    Dim iFound      As VbMsgBoxResult
    iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To iSearch
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)) <> Trim(txtSearch.Text) And i = iSearch Then
            iFound = MsgBox("Item Not Found! Please update ")
            cmdAddRecord.Enabled = FALSE
            Dim iControl As Control

            For Each iControl In Me.Controls
                If iControl.Name Like "txt*" Then iControl = vbNullString
            Next

            txtSearch.SetFocus
        End If
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)) = Trim(txtSearch.Text) Then
            txtLine.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            txtDescription.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            txtStyle.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            txtItem.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
            txtFabric.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            txtBrand.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
            txtTotalqty.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
            txtDate.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
            txtIssueDate1.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
            txtActualIssue1.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
            cmdAddRecord.Enabled = TRUE
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Add Button Code: (But it is wrong Because I cannot add it to the relevant style No Row)

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
    ''If txtIssueDate1.Text = "" Then
    '' MsgBox ("Fields cannot empty!")
    ''Else

    ''End If
    Dim iSearch     As Long, i As Long
    Dim iFound      As VbMsgBoxResult
    iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To iSearch
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)) = Trim(txtSearch.Text) Then

            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Dim AddNew As Range
            Set wks = Sheet1
            Set AddNew = wks.Range("I65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtIssueDate1.Text
            AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtActualIssue1.Text
            MsgBox ("Details are Entered!")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```